Spotlight Server Keeps Disabling
Yesterday Spotlight stopped returning results and sudo mdutil -s /returned Spotlight search is disabled. I tried all the different solutions found via search, but I could not re-enable Spotlight. I finally rebooted the computer, and that seems to fix the issue - Spotlight was indexing and running until I went to sleep. However, overnight, Spotlight is once again disabled. I confirmed this by running sudo mdutil -s / again. I do not know why this is happening.
I'm running macOS Sequoia 15.1
Here are all the different solutions I tried:
sudo mdutil -i on
sudo mdutil -a -i on
sudo mdutil -E

The following commands in tandem:
sudo mdutil -X /System/Volumes/Data
sudo mdutil -X /System/Volumes/Preboot
sudo mdutil -X /Volumes/Macintosh \HD
sudo mdutil -a -Esvp -i on /Volumes

Each one of these returned Spotlight server is disabled
I ran locate .metadata_never_index and it returned
/Library/Apple/System/Library/InstallerSandboxes/.metadata_never_index
/Library/InstallerSandboxes/.metadata_never_index

I also tried running /Library/Apple/System/Library/InstallerSandboxes/.metadata_never_index /Library/InstallerSandboxes/.metadata_never_index but it did not work because of SIP.
Finally, when I go to System Settings and attempt to add a folder in Search Privacy, I get Privacy List Error. The item couldn't be added or removed because of an unknown error.
I'm at a loss at what else to try.

Please specify your macOS version. Also, boot in Safe Mode and test. Any difference?

I'm running macOS Sequoia 15.1

I would start by updating to the current version (15.1.1 as of right now), just in case you’re triggering an obscure bug that has been fixed. Otherwise, boot in Safe Mode at bedtime and test the next morning.
